# Error sending data between components not related to BehaviorSubject Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem when passing data between unrelated components using **Services** and **`BehaviorSubject`**, the problem is when receiving the data the value of the variable Behavior arrives empty like this (""), I do not understand why I clarify my components do not have Nothing to do with each other.

My **service**:

```
@Injectable()
export class GestioOperacionesService {

    private enviaRecibe = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
    enviaRecibe$ = this.enviaRecibe.asObservable();

    // Store message, ready to show it to whoever asks.
    enviar(mensaje) {
        // function that will call who wants to transmit a message.
        this.enviaRecibe.next(mensaje);
    }
    constructor() { }
}
```

My component that sends the data: (I don't upload the whole component just the method:

```
 Procesar(data) {
    const urlModulo = moduloAGestionar.validarModuloGestionar(data.IdModulo);
    this.gestionServiceOperacion.enviar('Envia mensaje desde componente'); // esta linea envia el mensaje
    this.router.navigate(['/Clientes/Juridicos']);
    console.log(data);
  }
```

My receiving component:

```
 CargaDataOperaciones() {
    this.gestionServiceOperacion.enviaRecibe$.pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(mensaje => setTimeout(() => this.dataRecibida = mensaje, 0));
  }
```

This is the way in which I have declared the variable it receives:

```
public dataRecibida: string;
```

The latter would be the method that receives the information sent from the component and would show it in the view, but in empty arrives, I tried without the **TimeOut**, without the **pipe** without the **take** and nothing works.

Why is this ? What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code.
[Go through this code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcrcub)

Its working fine. May be you were not calling the function CargaDataOperaciones  correctly. Check it out.